# correct PID pseudocode

Tags: pid-controller

I was looking for simple pseudocodes for a PID controller and found [this](http://robotsforroboticists.com/pid-control/) code.
[image]

If I am not wrong this Ki_Prior is wrong and should be `e_integrated` otherwise we will also be adding this Ki gain with this term So according to the psuedocode should look something like this

```
I = I + e*iteration_time

D = (e -e_prior)/iteration_time

output = Kp*error + Ki *I + Kd *D
```

or am I missing something here ?

Comment: Considering the plots on the page you linked are hand drawn, I suppose the author couldn't get it to work himself as well. The pseudo code seems to be correct, however still missing key features.

Comment: The Kx are constants, so the use of Ki_prior is obviously very wrong here. You are right, replace Ki_prior with I_prior (to keep consistency with the rest of the notation), and also write I = I_prior+e*iteration_time

Comment: @Jeroen3 key features like ?

Comment: @Neil_UK shouldnt `I = I + e*iteration_time` work ?

Comment: Well, they are mostly implementation specific, but saturation arithmetic and integral windup protection.

Comment: @Jeroen3 Ah! I didnt think about them ,Thanks. but the pseudocode which I wrote seems correct ?

Comment: I=I+delta_I is what you write in code, the compiler evaluates the RHS, assigns the LHS to it. I=I_prior+delta_I is actually what happens, and matches the notation of the example, it's also often written I(t) = I(t-1)+delta_I. It makes explicit to you which time samples are involved, keeps you honest. When you come to implement things in DSP, and need pipelining, it's useful to have got used to using explicit subscripts, because then you'll need them.

Comment: If your iteration_time is constant (as it _should_ be), the calculations for integral and derivative can be simplified by modifying coefficients and using previous integral term.